# How to display a java script window in adobe acrobat

Tags: javascript, acrobat

In adobe acrobat I want to make a pdf file in which when the user is going to open it,it shows some content and asks user to click on agree or disagree button.When user click on agree button it shows original content of file and when click on disagree button the file automatically be closed without showing the original content.
Please tell me how I do the same by using adobe acrobat tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PageOpen event of the page where the document opens, initiate an alert with Yes and No as answer. Evaluate the response, and in the case of No, close the document without saving.

You might have a look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation (which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website), in particular the entries about `app.alert()`.

And that should do it…